# Initialize google maps api inside lightbox (colorbox, shadowbox etc) after click on link

Tags: google-maps, lightbox, google-geocoder

I have a list of links with addresses:

```
<a href="#location_google" data-address="Moscow" class="openmap"><span>Address</span></a>
<a href="#location_google" data-address="London" class="openmap"><span>Address</span></a>
<a href="#location_google" data-address="Tel Aviv" class="openmap"><span>Address</span></a>
```

This is my GMap script (from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)):

```
function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      codeAddress();
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            },
            scrollwheel: false
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_wrap'), mapOptions);

    }

    function codeAddress() {
      var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

I have an input with id="address" that is empty, this input will save my address from "data-address" parameter:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <div id="location_google">
        <div id="map_wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need after click on my link with address, get *jQuery(this)* address, put it on id="address" input, and then, open it in some lightbox. I tried before THIS [lightbox](http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/), but it didn't work for me...

To intialize lightbox on click:

```
jQuery("a.openmap").tosrus();
```

Comment: Please include codes of your lightbox.

Comment: I don't understand what has to be shown in the lightbox.  Do you want the (Google) map in the lightbox?

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Exactly!